# Trying to pass data through jquery ajax facing issue

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass data through jquery ajax but facing issue. I am getting data in the json format

> data:'{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user)+'}'

like this

```
user = {Tdcno: "tw5", Revision: "0", Revision_Date: "22/11/2017", P_Group: "Chain Link", Prod_Desc: "GI wire for chain link", …}
```

but after processing at this step it directly goes to failure.Any help would appreciated for resolving.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
     $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {
                alert("hi");        
                var user = {};
     user.Tdcno = $("[id*=Tdc_No]").val();
     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TDC.aspx/SaveFrmDetails",
                    data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("User has been added successfully.");
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
     });
                return false;
    });
        });
    </script>
```

c# code

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public  void SaveFrmDetails(User user)
    {
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TDC_PRODUCT1 VALUES(@Tdc_No, @Revision,@Revision_Date,@P_Group,@Prod_Desc,@N_I_Prd_Std,@Appln,@Frm_Supp,@Created_Date,@Created_By)"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please use Chrome Developer Tools to get the payload being sent to the server, and include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Never manually create json strings. It is error prone and more work than serializing them with JSON.stringify.

`'{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}'` produces invalid json because the property `user` is not properly quoted

Stringify the whole data object

```
data: JSON.stringify({user:user}})
```